# Problem driving 4 PhotoMos relays with Rasberry Pi and FET

Tags: relay, raspberry-pi

I am using 4 PhotoMos relays to switch some signal lines and have ended up the board below to switch a bank of four relays (the datasheet for these is attached at the end).

[image: breadboard render of transistor and four solid-state relay configuration]

The relays are powered via the 5v line and switched on via a GPIO pin attached to a transistor. I am using a Pi v3 and the standard power supply rated (5v, 2.5a) This setup seems to work in some instances and not others, specifically it reliably switches on 3 out the 4 relays (but not consistently the same 3). I have doubled checked the board for shorts or misconfiguration but all seems in order.

I am relatively inexperienced and heading out of my depth and would be grateful if someone could review the board and recommend whether it is good, bad or ugly and whether there is any modifications I need to make for reliable operation.

[image: screenshot of solid state relay datasheet KQAH615D]

Comment: Get a cheap DMM and measure your PhotoFet pin 2. If it's not being pulled down to about 0.1 volt or less, you're not driving the FET right. It would help if you included the model of the FET.

Comment: Thanks Beast. The part i am using is http://www.jaycar.com.au/pcb-mount-solid-state-dil-relay/p/SY4090. When I check the voltage across pins 1 an 2 it is ~= 1.1v (same for all whether they are actually operating correctly or not)

Comment: Also the transistor is a 2N222A NPN (http://www.jaycar.com.au/2n2222a-npn-transistor/p/ZT2298)

Comment: Measure pin 2 to ground.

Comment: (5V-Vd1-Vq1-Vrelay)/650 ohms =(5-.7-1.2-.2)/650 < 5ma (led trigger current ) reduce limiter resistor from 650 to  470 and  base resistor from 1k to 470

Comment: Thanks @ise5755 that has corrected the stability of the board when the relay outputs are not under load. Feel free to add this as an answer and I will mark it correct. There is another problem though. One side of each relay is connected to one of the lines from a USB thumbdrive and the other half to an output USB port. When the drive and the output are connected then either the relay for the USB GND or the 5v lines will not operate. When the drive is disconnected the relay starts operating correctly. Any ideas what may cause this?

Comment: Thanks, so you are trying to commutated the four lines of usb drive? if so, probably the drive is not reset properly  due to turn on time of relay  or high impedance of drive side consider add  220 ohms resistor between D+ and D- signals in case of none above work, try to use reed relay instead http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/219770/switch-two-usb-ports-via-relay

Comment: That worked reasonable well @ise5755, thank you.Given a few seconds delay between switching it looks stable. And many thanks for that link, very useful and I will adapt based on the information there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(5V-Vd1-Vq1-Vrelay)/650 ohms =(5-.7-1.2-.2)/650 < 5ma (led trigger current ) reduce limiter resistor from 650 to 470 and base resistor from 1k to 470